# Sqlite join multiple tables issue

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

Hi everybody hi have this three tables

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
   c1 integer,
   primary key (c1)
);
CREATE TABLE test2 (
   c1 integer,
   c2 integer,
   primary key (c2)
);    
CREATE TABLE test3 (
   c2 integer,
   c3 integer,
   primary key (c3)
);
```

and i've tried this query but returned all the table not the affected row

```
SELECT test1.c1, test2.c2, test3.c3
FROM test1
LEFT JOIN test2 ON test1.c1=test2.c1 AND test1.c1 = 1
LEFT JOIN test3 ON test2.c2=test3.c2
```

Comment: Please post sample Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in placing condition 'AND test1.c1 = 1' within LEFT JOIN.
It should be placed within WHERE like below:

```
SELECT test1.c1, test2.c2, test3.c3
FROM test1
LEFT JOIN test2 ON test1.c1=test2.c1
LEFT JOIN test3 ON test2.c2=test3.c2 
where test1.c1 = 1
```

When you put additional condition within LEFT JOIN (also OUTER and RIGHT) all records which don't match
will get null values and you get all rows from test1 table.

In your sql all records are fetched from test1 and next there is matching with test2 and test3 tables.
Condition 'AND test1.c1 = 1' works only for this LEFT JOIN, not for whole query.